# How to get data from user meta custom fields created with acf-pro plugin?

Tags: custom-field, user-meta

I need to get user meta from the database and WordPress has the awesome function get_user_meta() for this purpose but, the problem is I need not default meta field. I need to get data from a custom field created with ACF-pro. And I really confused about how to do this. I try:

```
$user_data = get_user_meta('19') 
print_r($user_data)
```

And among a large number of different data, I see what I need:

```
[user-sector] => Array ( [0] => a:3:{i:0;s:3:"602";i:1;s:3:"601";i:2;s:3:"584";} ) [_user-sector] => Array ( [0] => field_611d13578192e ) [user-country] => Array ( [0] => a:1:{i:0;s:2:"17";} ) [_user-country] => Array ( [0] => field_611d138e8192f ) )
```

Of course I tried using: get_user_meta('19', 'user-country') and also I tried using: get_user_meta('19', '_user-country') and of couse nothing as a result. The result is just an empty array. So is there really a method to get data from meta fields created with acf?

Comment: Have you looked at the ACF docs? https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/how-to-get-values-from-a-user/

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to write about it, yes of course I checked "Get values from a user"  out in the ACF docs. And try to implement the recommendation with the same result = nothing(

Comment: Have you tried `get_user_meta('19', 'user-country', true)`?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I use:

```
<?php global $current_user; wp_get_current_user(); ?>
<?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { 
echo 'User ID: ' . $current_user->ID . "<br>"; 
?>
<a href="<?php echo $current_user->favorite_url;?>">View</a> <?php
 } 
else { wp_loginout(); } ?>
```

You can just use the ID you have and change $current_user->ID to $current_user->user-country